# Memory management in Objective c

Tags: objective-c

1. I am new in objective c and also in development field, and i want to know that when we quit our application then os automatically release or finish our resources that we retain during our application so why we need to do it explicitly(release or autorelease in obj c)?
2. My second question is that i am facing problem in when i release object of app delegate class in rootViewcontroller class in dealloc method then my program is crash when again i am going to go in controller class like follwing.

   -(void) viewDidLoad
   {
   TestAppDelegate * object = (TestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   }

   -(void)dealloc
   {[object release];
   [super dealloc];}

Comment: The above code won't even compile, much less crash - `object` is local to the `-viewDidLoad` method, and attempting to use it in `-dealloc` results in a compile error. If you want real help, please post real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should release or autorelease objects in order to make all the objects execute their -()dealloc's. When process finishes OS clears all the memory occupied by process but it cannot clear some other resources (mutexes, semaphores, maybe something else) because they are kernel objects and might be used by different processes. So OS cannot know whether to delete these objects as initial process finished. Developer should clear such objects himself and this is done usually in dealloc methods of proper objects.
2. It's not clear when crash happens. Could you clarify?

Comment: thanx for answering me, but i have a confusion on that when every object is going to destroy(using release or autorelease) then it called it dealloc method, so you mean that every object has its own dealloch method???

Comment: On second question i am facing problem when i used of appdelegate object in rootviewcontroller then i want to go away from scope of rootviewcontroller but app still run or i still remain in the scope of application then i release object of appdelegate because having no use in rootviewcontroller, but when i again comeback in scope of rootviewcontroller then it crash, but i think it should not be crashed because it again call -(void)viewDidLoad of rootviewcontroller and it should again reallocate of appDelegate object but it not happen. So can you explain?